# Unable to UPDATE / REPLACE multiple stored Images in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a MySql dB containing Images(BLOB) & Text data types, I'm able to Insert & Delete text & Images to and from Database, I'm unable to replace an existing image using the UPDATE query. Code executes without errors but not functional.Your help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

```
//UPDATE METHOD
@FXML private void UpdateData(ActionEvent ae){
try{
String sql= "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET SLNO=?,NAME=?,DES=?,IMAGE1=?,IMAGE2=?,IMAGE3=? where  SLNO='"+slnoField.getText()+"'";

pst.setString(1, slnoField.getText());
pst.setString(2, nameField.getText());
pst.setString(3, desField.getText());

fis1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
pst.setBinaryStream(4, (InputStream)fis1, (int)file1.length());

fis2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
pst.setBinaryStream(5, (InputStream)fis2, (int)file2.length());

fis3 = new FileInputStream(file3);
pst.setBinaryStream(6, (InputStream)fis3, (int)file3.length());

pst.execute();
pst.close();
}catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e)
}
}
```

Comment: `'"+slnoField.getText()+"'` really? And what is `pst` where is it instantiated?

Comment: pst is the preparedStatement, instantiated as a Global Variable

Comment: I already guessed that, but how do you think `pst` *knows* how to use the local `sql` variable?

Comment: Having a prepared statement as a global variable is a big no, it should be local to that method.

Comment: Thank you RC & Mark, instantiating the prepared statement locally worked :) for updating Image in 1 field(ImageView field), I have edited the original question seeking help on updating images in multiple fields. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a prepared statement

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Go through this video, shows how to update an image in the Time frame of 6:04 to 10:00 minutes range:

> https://youtu.be/PUFNtreMHv8?t=6m4s

Comment: Adding statement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); makes no difference

Comment: can you post the code snippet, how you are passing the global variable "file1"

Comment: Thanks Senthil, including prepared statement works great to update single Image field, I have now edited the original question seeking how to update multiple image fields.

Comment: For one or more file selection ref here : For http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm

Comment: Hi Senthil, thanks for the reference. The Filechooosers in my program work fine, the issue here is that I have 3 image fields (images displayed in ImageView), if an end user wants to replace lets say any 1 of the 3 images, the code should accommodate that, currently if I want to replace any one image & to avoid a NPE I'm having to update (i.e insert new images)in the other two fields also.Any suggestions?

Comment: How you did for image1, follow the same for other two image field as well. Advantage is you will aways use update query only because all the image1, image2, image3  are present in same field. So you will go for update, whether you picked the image. Only update the corresponding column alone instead of updating all.